# scala matching optional set of characters

Tags: regex, scala

I am using scala regex to extract a token from a URL

my url is http://www.google.com?x=10&id=x10_23&y=2
here I want to extract the value of x10 in front of id. note that _23 is optional and may or may not appear but if it appears it must be removed.

The regex which I have written is

```
val regex = "^.*id=(.*)(\\_\\d+)?.*$".r
x match {
    case regex(id) => print(id)
    case _ => print("none")
}
```

this should work because `(\\_\\d+)?` should make the _23 optional as a whole.

So I don't understand why it prints none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your pattern `^.*id=(.*)(\\_\\d+)?.*$` actually puts `x10_23&y=2` into Group 1 because of the 1st greedy dot matching subpattern. Since `(_\d+)?` is optional, the first greedy subpattern does not have to yield any characters to that capture group.

You can use

```
val regex = "(?s).*[?&]id=([^\\W&]+?)(?:_\\d+)?(?:&.*)?".r
val x = "http://www.google.com?x=10&id=x10_23&y=2"
x match {
    case regex(id) => print(id)
    case _ => print("none")
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/qabbGO) ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN6kL2/2))

Note that there is no need defining `^` and `$` - that pattern is anchored in Scala by default. `(?s)` ensures we match the full input string even if it contains newline symbols.

Comment: This did not work for `x = "http://www.google.com?x=10&id=x10_a_20&y=2"`. in this case the answer should be `x10_a` but this produces output of `x10`. it seems to truncate everything after an `_` but I want to ignore `_\d+` pattern. (_ and any number of digits).

Comment: You can use `(?s).*[?&]id=([^\\W&]+?)(?:_\\d+)?(?:&.*)?`

Comment: Just to clarify: making the preceding to `_\d+` subpattern *lazy* (with `?` in `[^\\W&]+?`) we can make sure we are still inside that query argument and do not consume the last `_xx` in that argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea instead of using a regular expression to extract tokens would be to use the built-in URI Java class with its `getQuery()` method. There you can split the query by `=` and then check if one of the pair starts with `id=` and extract the value.

For instance (just as an example):

```
val x = "http://www.google.com?x=10&id=x10_23&y=2"
val uri = new URI(x)

uri.getQuery.split('&').find(_.startsWith("id=")) match {
    case Some(param) => println(param.split('=')(1).replace("_23", ""))
    case None => println("None")
}
```

I find it simpler to maintain that the regular expression you have, but that's just my thought!

Comment: will not work because you cannot hardcode _23 in code. this case be any pattern like _123 or _444.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch You can use `replaceAll` with a regular expression